# Manually change Windows 8.1 service boot mode without access to OS

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-services

So recently I ran into a bit of trouble with the driver FVEVOL.SYS taking up large amounts of the CPU at random times, to fix this I disabled the service using the command prompt to stop the driver from booting, now Windows refuses to boot.

My question is, is there a way to manually edit a file to change the boot mode of this driver without access to windows?

I can access to the drive via a Windows 10 recovery ISO on a disc as well, so if anything needs to be edited I can do it. Already tried to run the command prompt from the drive with Windows 8.1 and it didn't work as it modified it locally on the recovery ISO. Somewhat same problem with the Windows 8 "Advanced Option" troubleshoot mode of running a command prompt, but that didn't work as it wouldn't let me change to the C drive.

Also I understand FVEVOL.SYS is Bitlocker, and no, none of my drives were encrypted. In fact I didn't even have access to Bitlocker on the 8.1 control panel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit the service in the Windows registry offline, find the service key"FVEVOL", highlight the key and in the right panes set the "Start" value to 3 for it to start on boot, or 0 for disabled.

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services